# ASP.Net Core App Output in a Console Window?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

Before I upgraded to VS 2019 (99% sure that's the only thing that changed) my ASP.net Core app ran in it's own console window. Now, it only outputs to the output window of VS.

How can I make my app open it's own window once again?

[image]

Comment: Are you debugging the application directly or running it in IIS Express?

Comment: This has nothing to do with VS. The logging output is controlled by the application's logging configuration in `Startup`, how the application is executed (eg in-process has no console to begin with) and the ASP.NET Core version itself (older versions didn't have in-place execution)

Comment: I added my debug options... I've tried the different Launch options..

Comment: IIS Express will not launch the application in a console window. If you choose to run it outside of IIS Express (select your project name instead of IIS Express in the Start Debugging dropdown menu) it should run directly in a console window.

Comment: Do you mean the Profile dropdown? I've changed the profile, and the launch dropdown both to the project. No change.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As @Valuator said, inside your dropdown menu which you can switch to use your project name as debugger Emulator. 
Start debugging a default console will pop up.

[image]

Comment: This has bugged me for more than a year. Thank you so much! Works like a charm - Console window pops up as expected. I've lost countless hours to this trying to adjust logging / Serilog / env variables - you name it. Wish I could add more votes!